# ImportError in Compiled exe, but not in the script

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyodbc

I wrote a small python script that interacts with the database. I wanted to create an exe of the script file and then send it to the end user instead of sending the script file itself. I am using pytoexe to create the exe file .

This is how my setup.py file looks like now

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
    console=["Test.py"],
    zipfile = None,
    data_files=[("",
                 ["config.xml"]),
                ],
    name='Test',
    version='1.0.0',
    url='',
    license='',
    author='test user',
    author_email='',
    description='',
    #package_dir = {'': 'Lib'},
    py_modules =['pyodbc']
    #packages = ['pyodbc']
)
```

I run the script using the following command line

> python setup.py py2exe --bundle 2

While creating the exe , py2exe displays this message

> The following modules appear to be missing
>   ['ElementC14N', 'pyodbc']

However the exe is generated. Now, whenever I run this exe , i get this message

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "Test.py", line 4, in 
>   ImportError: No module named pyodbc

The script that I have runs fine if i execute the script. Its only that when i create the exe , the exe does not work and gives me this message .

Any help would be appreciated .

Note : 
I have the following imports in the script file

1. import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
2. import pyodbc

The other error ["ElementC14N"] that is present while py2exe is generating is the exe, I believe is due to the xml file that I am reading settings from. any help to resolve that issue would be praiseworthy as well .

Thanks

Comment: I've read a number of things that say you need an `options = { "py2exe": { "includes": "decimal, datetime" } }` `setup` argument to get `pyodbc` to work.

Comment: Can you please forward me that link ?

Comment: Just Google `"py2exe" "pyodbc"`.

Comment: but that is true only if I get the exception RuntimeError: Unable to import decimal .. but I am not getting that exception .. 
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/PyODBC

Answer (score 2):

thank you all ....

this is what i did and it started working for me

```
options = {"py2exe":{"packages":"encodings",
                     "includes":["pyodbc",
                                 "datetime", "decimal"],
                     "bundle_files":2,
                     "optimize":2},},
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me :(
Could you please give the complete setup.py script as an example ?

My setup.py looks like this : http://pastebin.com/b8M81Si5
The error looks like : http://pastebin.com/YLFixUzC

TIA

Comment: What did you do to overcome the missing module ElementC14N?

Comment: @MichaelDavidWatson : I am still a naive at python but i think this usually means that the library you are trying to use is not properly "referenced" .